# Bash redirection doesn't work for SQLite command

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Bash allows for piping to stdin from another command in this way...

```
$ ls /bin/aud* | cat
/bin/audacity
/bin/audiocompose
/bin/audiosend
...
```

...and this way as well:

```
$ cat <(ls /bin/aud*)
/bin/audacity
/bin/audiocompose
/bin/audiosend
...
```

Yet when I tried the same patterns to send a query to SQLite, I got this
from the first form...

```
$ echo "select count(*) from urls;" | \
    sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History
5983
```

...but this error on the second:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History \
   <(echo "select count(*) from urls;")
Error: near "/": syntax error
```

This was surprising... The SQL statement is not interpolated or messed up by the shell:

```
$ echo "select count(*) from urls;"
echo "select count(*) from urls;"
```

And it's not about the `echo` either - it can definitely be used in redirecting:

```
$ cat <(echo Foo)
Foo
```

All I can think of is that somehow the path to the database file is  misinterpreted and passed-in as also the SQL statement... (that's the only place containing a '/' - the only explanation for a 'syntax error near /').

Why, though? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second form of I/O redirection (`<(cmd)`) simply doesn't behave the same way as the first form (`cmd | other-cmd`).

The first connects the output of `cmd` to the input of `other-cmd`, but the second substitutes either a `/dev/fd` path or a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) path in for the command. The standard output of `cmd` is tied to the other end of that pipe, but this only appears equivalent with commands like `cat` which will either read from stdin or from a file path. `sqlite3` does not behave that way, so it exposes the difference between the two forms of I/O redirection.

`sqlite3` [expects](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sqlite3) optional SQL statements after the DB path, so it tries to parse this substituted path as SQL and fails.

Incidentally, this means that you don't need the I/O redirection at all. This command does what you're wanting more efficiently than either form you've tried:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History "select count(*) from urls"
```

Note that you don't need the statement-terminating semicolon when passing a single SQL statement to `sqlite3` as a command line parameter.

Comment: Note however you can get it working by doing `other-cmd < <(cmd)`

Comment: @Patrick: Your comment is the perfect addition to Warren's answer - it's crystal clear now. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo <(echo "hi")
/dev/fd/63
```

`/dev/fd/63` is not SQL, therefore `sqlite3` fails with the indicated error message. `cat` by contrast is pretty good at reading files (or also from standard input). The named pipe or `/dev/fd` file of the `<(list)` construct created is not standard input.